# How to write a file based on array in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

```
var z = ['111','222','333']
var x = ['zzz','yyy','xxx']
var fs = require('fs');
for(var y = 0; y < 3; y++)
    fs.writeFile('z[y].json', x[y]);
```

Trying to do something of the above sort in casper/node.js, what would be the best way to go about it.

Looked into the possibility of using filestreams and such but was unable to gain an exact understanding of how to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

CasperJS is built on top of PhantomJS has access to its [File System Module](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/). That module provides a streaming version and a single invocation version.

#### Single invocation

Since the array that you have is already in memory, it probably won't be too bad if you just create a string with the file contents and write it completely:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var x = ['zzz', 'yyy', 'xxx'];
var s = "";
for(var y = 0; y < 3; y++)
    s + = x[y] + "\n";
fs.write('text.txt', s);
```

#### File stream

To use a file stream, you need to [open the stream first](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/method/open.html) and then write to it:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var x = ['zzz', 'yyy', 'xxx'];
var f = fs.open("text.txt", 'w');
for(var y = 0; y < 3; y++)
    f.write('text.txt', x[y] + "\n");
f.close();
```

#### Single invocation appender

Of course you can also use an appender, but it's inefficient, because the file is opened and closed multiple times:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var x = ['zzz', 'yyy', 'xxx'];
for(var y = 0; y < 3; y++)
    fs.write('text.txt', x[y] + "\n", 'a');
```

#### Single string into multiple files

It seems you want to write single different strings into different files. You don't need streams for that at all. Just use the first suggestion in a loop:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var z = ['111','222','333']
var x = ['zzz', 'yyy', 'xxx'];
for(var y = 0; y < 3; y++)
    fs.write(z[y]+'.json', x[y]);
```

---

Please note that PhantomJS (and CasperJS) has a different execution environment than node.js. You can't simply use node modules in CasperJS or PhantomJS.